# How to use turn variable to synchronize in C?

Tags: c, ipc, shared-memory

I am new to semaphore and I am trying to let my child process to execute the code one by one using the turn variable, which means that if it isnt the child's turn, it will have to wait for its turn (when turn increments). And I was supposed to print an output of

```
I am child 0
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
I am child 1
10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
etc.
```

But when I run the code, it gave me a segmentation fault, core dumped error. Anyone can assist on this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define NUM_PROCESSES 5

int main() {
    int i, j, pid;
    int *turn;
    int sharedid;
    //create a share memory region
    sharedid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, 4*sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT | 0600);
   //attach turn to the shared memory region
    turn = (int *) shmat(sharedid, NULL,0);
   // initialize it to 0
    *turn = 0;
    
    
    for(i=0; i<NUM_PROCESSES; i++) {
        if((pid = fork()) == 0) {
        
            break;
    }   
    }
    
    if(pid != 0) {
       while (*turn != i); 
       printf("I am child %d\n", i);

        for(j = i*10; j<i*10 + 10; j++){
            printf("%d ", j);
            fflush(stdout);
            usleep(250000);
        }

        printf("\n\n");
        *turn = *turn + 1;
          
    }
    else {
        for(i=0; i<NUM_PROCESSES; i++){ 
            wait(NULL);
        }
    shmdt(turn);
    shmctl(sharedid, IPC_RMID, 0);
          
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say `turn = 0;` you mean `*turn = 0;`.

Comment: This `turn = 0;` assigns a `NULL` pointer to `turn`. When you dereference it later, you cause undefined behaviour restulting in your crash.

Comment: `if(pid != 0) {
       while (*turn != i); 
       printf("I am child %d\n", i);` <<-- no, you're not.

Comment: how do i change that line?

Comment: With an editor.

Comment: what i mean is i need the parent process to spawn off 5 child processes to print the output, but each child process needs to wait for its turn to execute. How can i achieve that?

Comment: I commented the remaining code from *turn = 0 afterwards, and it gives me segmentation fault error, can I know how can i initialize the turn variable into zero? Thank!

Comment: Many functions can fail for a variety of reasons. They usually report on via their return values, possibly with the assistance of the `errno` variable.  You *need* to check for and handle such errors where you in fact care whether the function call succeeded.  And that is not something to add later, for (i) going back and adding that to all the relevant function calls later is far more difficult than putting it in when you write the calls in the first place, and (ii) you need it even more during development than in production.

Comment: Having examined the code currently presented fairly carefully, I see no particular reason to expect that it would segfault, unless because `shmget` or `shmat` fails (which, as previously mentioned, will go unnoticed).  A similar program derived from the code presented did not segfault for me.  HOWEVER, you (and I) still do have data races involving the contents of the shared-memory segment.  In principle, that means *anything* could happen.

Comment: Note also that there is no semaphore anywhere to be seen in the code presented, nor have you asked about how to create or use one (and hint: a semaphore is the wrong tool for this job).  Tags edited.

Comment: Any variable that is going to be shared between threads or processes, including one in shared memory, needs to be made `atomic` and accessed with appropriate atomic operations.  Otherwise it is a data race and very likely will not execute correctly.  For starters, `while (*turn != i); ` may very well be "optimized" into an infinite loop, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @NateEldredge, if by `atomic` you mean `_Atomic` then that is sufficient but not necessary.  It is also sufficient to protect access via an appropriate synchronization object, such as a mutex or a semaphore.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: True, but this code doesn't have any of those either.  I thought the intent was to use a shared counter variable in place of any more elaborate synchronization.